# Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc library and refresh token

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to retrieve the reviews from our business account.

For this I'm using the Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc library for .net https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/ and following this example https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc.

The library is supposed to use the refresh token automatically but for some reason after 1 hour when the access token expires we lost access to the reviews.

Here is my implementation:

```
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            Scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage" },
            DataStore = new FileDataStore(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MyGoogleStorage"), true)
            //DataStore = new FileDataStore(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Drive.Api.Auth.Store"))
        });

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        return "our email address";
    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }
}
```

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
        AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (result.Credential != null)
    {
        var accessToken = result.Credential.Token.AccessToken;
        var client = new RestClient("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/116326379071192580211/locations/6608127685860731136/reviews?access_token=" + accessToken);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        GoogleReviewsModel googleReviews = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleReviewsModel>(response.Content);

        return View("Index", googleReviews);
    }
    else
    {
        return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
    }
}
```

```
public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
{
    protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
    {
        get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
    }
}
```

The reviews are from our own company so we don't to logins from different users. What I want to achieve is to login the first time with our company logins and then automatically refresh the access token with the refresh token so the reviews are always visible in the website,

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

After 1 hour the response I get from the following code is this:

```
var accessToken = result.Credential.Token.AccessToken;
var client = new RestClient("https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/116326379071192580211/locations/6608127685860731136/reviews?access_token=" + accessToken);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

> ""message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.\",\n](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%5C%22,%5Cn)    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"

result.Credential contains both the access token and the refresh token so it seems to read the file in app_data. But the access code seems to be expired and is not being refreshed at this point and is not asking to login again neither:

```
var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
        AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: mind checking your /App_Data/MyGoogleStorage tell me whats in there?

Comment: @DaImTo inside the folder the library is creating a file with the name "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-our email address" and inside of it there is a json containing the access token, the refresh token, etc.

Comment: ok is "our email address" your actually email address? or is it the words "our email address"?  If it is an email im curious if it could be the @ thats the problem and if is just the words you have written then im wondering if its having issues with the Spaces.   Want to change it to something simple like "user1"?

Comment: The fact that its not refreshing it makes me think that the code in the library that searches for the file cant find the file.  Which could imply a bug in the library that could simply be solved by changing the name to something less controversial.   In the meantime i have pinged one of the devs on the library she may have other ideas.

Comment: @DaImTo it is an actual address, the one from the google account. I tried also with a guid number and same result. I think the library is finding the file because if I remove it it ask for authentication in google again and generates a new one. I have put an edit with the response I get after 1 hour.

Comment: Why aren't you using the [Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.MyBusinessAccountManagement.v1) package?

Comment: @DaImTo I tried but I could get the account with var accounts = await service.Accounts.List().ExecuteAsync(); but couldn't find a way to get the reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually "telling the library" to refresh the access token, you are directly using the token that had been stored, and is now expired. Your code that looks like this:

```
var accessToken = result.Credential.Token.AccessToken;
```

should look like this:

```
var accessToekn = await result.Credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
```

The `GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync` method will check if the access token needs refreshing and do so when needed.

Comment: oh true! I have changed that and now after 1 hour when the access token is expired it is asking me for authorization again instead of responding "Request had invalid authentication credentials". Is it necessary to add soemthing extra to make it use the refresh token?

Comment: Hmmm, it shouldn't, when that happens, can you double check that you have a refresh_token (and you haven't revoked it or anything)? After one hour, can you manually call result.Credential.RefreshAccessTokenAsync and see whether that fails?

Comment: okay, I just noticed that this time I didn't have the refresh token and this is only part of the response the first time you authorise but no the next ones. You saved my week thank very much!

Comment: Yes, exactly, the refresh token only comes when you exchange the auth code for the token. When you refresh a token usually only an access token is returned. The library does takes that into account see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/7be1099352992a3247660486fe9129fe40774b97/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/UserCredential.cs#L162)